# How to fix [The method put(String, Boolean) in the type ContentValues is not applicable for the arguments (Boolean, Boolean)]

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to learn how to develop an Android App and am trying to re-write 
`Notepadv3Solution {http://developer.android.com/training/notepad/index.html}` from modifying it for my own purposes.

In the method `createTask` (nr the bottom), I get the  error `The method put(String, Boolean) in the type ContentValues is not applicable for the arguments (Boolean, Boolean)`. I've added a boolean field for the database, adding it also to the `createTask` method.  How can I get it the boolean field to work?

```
package com.superiorxc.taskcentral;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class TasksDbAdapter {

    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String KEY_BODY = "body";
    public static final Boolean KEY_COMPLETE = true;

    private static final String TAG = "TasksDbAdapter";
    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;    

    /**
     * Database creation sql statement
     */
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table tbl_tasks (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + "title text not null, body text, complete boolean not null);";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "db_taskcentral";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "tbl_tasks";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private final Context mCtx;    

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl_tasks");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }    

    /**
     * Constructor - takes the context to allow the database to be
     * opened/created
     * 
     * @param ctx the Context within which to work
     */
    public TasksDbAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.mCtx = ctx;
    }

    /**
     * Open the db_taskcentral database. If it cannot be opened, try to create a new
     * instance of the database. If it cannot be created, throw an exception to
     * signal the failure
     * 
     * @return this (self reference, allowing this to be chained in an
     *         initialization call)
     * @throws SQLException if the database could be neither opened or created
     */
    public TasksDbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }   

    /**
     * Create a new task using the title and body provided. If the task is
     * successfully created return the new rowId for that note, otherwise return
     * a -1 to indicate failure.
     * 
     * @param title the title of the task
     * @param body the body of the task
     * @return rowId or -1 if failed
     */
    public long createTask(String title, String body, Boolean complete) {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
        initialValues.put(KEY_BODY, body);
        initialValues.put(KEY_COMPLETE,complete);


        return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }    

}
```

Comment: `initialValues.put(KEY_COMPLETE,complete);`, the key must be a `String` but you declared it as a `Boolean`.

Comment: why not post that as an answer? @ZouZou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `KEY_COMPLETE` to

```
public static final String KEY_COMPLETE = "complete";
```

You want it to reference what you named your column in the database.

You can think of **ContentValues** as a `Map<String,Object>` where the key is the name of the database column and the object is what you want to put into the row for that column.

Comment: Ahhh, thank you.  I thought I was declaring the fields, I wanted a yes/no field, so tried to declare a Boolean field.  I realise it was a label (of sorts) rather than the field itself.

Comment: yup, it can be confusing at first.  The database columns themselves are declared in the DATABASE_CREATE string.

Comment: NSjonas, yes I'm slowly picking things up... Will be a while though before things are clear...

Answer (score -1):

If you are asking "How to convert a Boolean to a String" then the easiest way is this:

`String.valueOf(Boolean)`

as in the following code:

```
    Boolean b = false;
    String aString = String.valueOf(b);
    System.out.println(aString);
```

Comment: No, I am not.  I now realise I thought I declaring fields in a table somehow, but I was actually defining 'labels'.

Answer (score -1):

One solution would be to change

```
public static final Boolean KEY_COMPLETE = true;
```

to

```
public static final String KEY_COMPLETE = "true";
```

Comment: That would likely throw and error because there is no column named true on the table.